# Javascript How to select checkbox based on delimited string with values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have similar like below mass checkboxes which I want to select based on database value. If I dump database value into string like DC0|100;DK0|100;DM0-SRM|200;DR0|300 (; delimited or something else). How do I select checkbox based on values using JAVASCRIPT or AJAX

Below are sample checkbox:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='systemclient[]' name='systemclient[]' value='DB0|100' /> 
<input type='checkbox' id='systemclient[]' name='systemclient[]' value='DB5|100' /> 
<input type='checkbox' id='systemclient[]' name='systemclient[]' value='DC0|100' /> 
<input type='checkbox' id='systemclient[]' name='systemclient[]' value='DE0|100' /> 
<input type='checkbox' id='systemclient[]' name='systemclient[]' value='DG0|200' /> 
<input type='checkbox' id='systemclient[]' name='systemclient[]' value='DG0|300' /> 
<input type='checkbox' id='systemclient[]' name='systemclient[]' value='DK0|100' /> 
<input type='checkbox' id='systemclient[]' name='systemclient[]' value='DL0|200' /> 
<input type='checkbox' id='systemclient[]' name='systemclient[]' value='DL0|300' /> 
<input type='checkbox' id='systemclient[]' name='systemclient[]' value='DM0-SRM|200' /> 
<input type='checkbox' id='systemclient[]' name='systemclient[]' value='DM0-SRM|300' /> 
<input type='checkbox' id='systemclient[]' name='systemclient[]' value='DM0-SUS|210' /> 
<input type='checkbox' id='systemclient[]' name='systemclient[]' value='DM0-SUS|310' /> 
<input type='checkbox' id='systemclient[]' name='systemclient[]' value='DR0|200' /> 
<input type='checkbox' id='systemclient[]' name='systemclient[]' value='DR0|300' />
<input type='checkbox' id='systemclient[]' name='systemclient[]' value='DV0|100' /> 
<input type='checkbox' id='systemclient[]' name='systemclient[]' value='DX0|100' />
```

Comment: you should edit your question, hard to read like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8ubk5c0f/2/

```
  $(function(){
        var stringFromServer = "DC0|100;DK0|100;DM0-SRM|200;DR0|300";
        var arrayOfValues = stringFromServer.split(";");
        var $checkboxes = $("input[type=checkbox]");
        $checkboxes.each(function(idx, element){
            if(arrayOfValues.indexOf(element.value) != -1){
                element.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
            }
            else{
                element.removeAttribute("checked");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: you guys are the best. :)

Comment: How to I use same function after HTML document is loaded ? since check boxes are generated during php page load.

Comment: this function only happens after HTML has been loaded. just make sure you have jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. See **[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/srmpzv5o/)**

```
var queryRes = "DC0|100;DK0|100;DM0-SRM|200;DR0|300";

// split string result by ';' char
var resArray = queryRes.split(';');

// Iterate splite items
resArray.forEach(function(item){
    // Select checkbox using value got from query and 
    // set its 'checked' attribute to TRUE
    $('input[type="checkbox"][value="' + item + '"]').attr('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need unique id's on your input elements.  In your example code, all of the input elements have id='systemclient[]'.

I'm assuming you have the string data from your database in JavaScript and just need help checking checkboxes that match the parsed string.

To parse the string:

```
var stringArray = myDataString.split(";");  //where ";" is the string delimiter
```

Iterate over your checkboxes and look for a match

```
$("input[name*='systemclient[]']").each(function(){
   console.log($(this));  //verify you're able to target the element
   if($.inArray($(this).val(), stringArray) !== -1) {
       $(this).prop('checked', true);
   } else {
       $(this).prop('checked', false);
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what libraries you have at your disposal [vanilla JS =)] you would split your string by delimiter of choice into array then iterate the array, looking up the checkbox by dom query select all then set the dom node checked property to true.

```
 var foos = str.split(';');
 foos.map(function(foo){ 
   var checkbox = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox'[value='" + foo + "']");
   checkbox.checked = true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help.